# How to perform 3DES encryption in Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, encryption, yii, 3des

I have a legacy Yii PHP system that is performing 3DES Encryption.

```
$data = 'id=1,username=admin,email=webmaster@example.com';
$encrypted_key = mhash(MHASH_SHA1,"foo_bar_key");
$encrypted_value = $StringHelper::encrypt($data, $encrypted_key); 
echo $encrypted_value 
//output => "0G8ITzc32wvqpDIjt6O7tZV9VKwU8KK7p0xI%2Fa%2FjiPOR%2FLrpfvsfMg9fyV2vAHgf"
```

I'm trying to get this same encrypted value in Ruby using 3DES encryption but I am not able to get it.

```
require 'openssl'
require 'mhash'
require 'base64'

@data = "id=1,username=admin,email=webmaster@example.com"
@encrypted_key = Mhash.sha1("foo_bar_key")

cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher.new('des-ede-cbc')
cipher.encrypt
cipher.key = @encrypted_key
output = cipher.update(@data)

puts output 
# output => "\xFC\xCAR\xE2L\xB1\x1A\xCA\x83E\x9C\xEEA\xFD\x9D'I\v\x8E9\xFA4\x14\x1F&\xBFR\x8A\xD3\xBDL\xC64\xABf\xCD\x85\x87\x88^"
#Base64.encode64(output) => "/MpS4kyxGsqDRZzuQf2dJ0kLjjn6NBQfJr9SitO9TMY0q2bNhYeIXg==\n"
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: try encoding it in base64 - http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html

Comment: No luck, I get the output in Ruby:  "/MpS4kyxGsqDRZzuQf2dJ0kLjjn6NBQfJr9SitO9TMY0q2bNhYeIXg==\n"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427477/encrypting-decrypting-3des-in-ruby

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to find the `$StringHelper::encrypt` function, but if it is compatible, you just need to also perform `cipher.final` in your Ruby code and concatenate the output of `update` and `final` as clearly specified in the [instructions](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html).

Comment: Does this help, how are you faring?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/168731

'man enc' on my system says:

```
    des-ede3-cbc       Three key triple DES EDE in CBC mode
    des-ede3           Three key triple DES EDE in ECB mode
```

- des3               Alias for des-ede3-cbc

  ```
  des-ede3-cfb       Three key triple DES EDE CFB mode
  des-ede3-ofb       Three key triple DES EDE in OFB mode
  ```